# How to display random and unique object from array on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, math

The below function will display a random object from the array, passing the index number to `setIndex(index)`. I want to display a random and unique object. How do I achieve this?

```
const length = array.length
const randomScenario = () => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    setIndex(index);
 }
```

Comment: You call add a `onClick={randomScenario}` to your button?

Comment: @GabrielPichot, he wants to know the way to make setIndex() as well.

Comment: Then something `const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)`; and then `const item = array[index]` should work no?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing great but you've missed `useState` to achieve this.

Here's a little example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App() {

  const array = ["hi", "bye", "etc..."];
  const [index, setIndex] = useState();
  const length = array.length

  const randomScenario = () => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    setIndex(index);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {randomScenario()}}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <p> {!index && index !== 0 ? 'Click to see magic' : array[index]} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";

const arr = ["car", "truck", "crane", "ship"];
const length = arr.length;

export default function Home() {
  const [word, setWord] = React.useState<string>("");
  const randomScenario = () :void => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    setIndex(index);
  };

  const setIndex = (index: number): void => {
    setWord(arr[index]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p id="show-object">{word}</p>
      <button onClick={randomScenario}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code snippet as an answer.

Comment: It's TS version FYI.